# New DotNet Core VSTS Agent in a Docker Container

Tags: docker, .net-core, azure-devops-self-hosted-agent

Trying to create a self-hosted agent in Docker running dotnet core?

I created my Agent using the following
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/docker?view=azure-devops

The below seems like a pretty standard setup, How can i change it so that my docker container can also build dotnetcore project?

This is for an windows box

**Docker**

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2019

WORKDIR /azp

COPY start.ps1 .

CMD powershell .\start.ps1
```

**start.ps1**

```
if (-not (Test-Path Env:AZP_URL)) {
  Write-Error "error: missing AZP_URL environment variable"
  exit 1
}

if (-not (Test-Path Env:AZP_TOKEN_FILE)) {
  if (-not (Test-Path Env:AZP_TOKEN)) {
    Write-Error "error: missing AZP_TOKEN environment variable"
    exit 1
  }

  $Env:AZP_TOKEN_FILE = "\azp\.token"
  $Env:AZP_TOKEN | Out-File -FilePath $Env:AZP_TOKEN_FILE
}

Remove-Item Env:AZP_TOKEN

if (Test-Path Env:AZP_WORK) {
  New-Item $Env:AZP_WORK -ItemType directory | Out-Null
}

New-Item "\azp\agent" -ItemType directory | Out-Null

# Let the agent ignore the token env variables
$Env:VSO_AGENT_IGNORE = "AZP_TOKEN,AZP_TOKEN_FILE"

Set-Location agent

Write-Host "1. Determining matching Azure Pipelines agent..." -ForegroundColor Cyan

$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$(Get-Content ${Env:AZP_TOKEN_FILE})"))
$package = Invoke-RestMethod -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic $base64AuthInfo")} "$(${Env:AZP_URL})/_apis/distributedtask/packages/agent?platform=win-x64&`$top=1"
$packageUrl = $package[0].Value.downloadUrl

Write-Host $packageUrl

Write-Host "2. Downloading and installing Azure Pipelines agent..." -ForegroundColor Cyan

$wc = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$wc.DownloadFile($packageUrl, "$(Get-Location)\agent.zip")

Expand-Archive -Path "agent.zip" -DestinationPath "\azp\agent"

try
{
  Write-Host "3. Configuring Azure Pipelines agent..." -ForegroundColor Cyan

  .\config.cmd --unattended `
    --agent "$(if (Test-Path Env:AZP_AGENT_NAME) { ${Env:AZP_AGENT_NAME} } else { ${Env:computername} })" `
    --url "$(${Env:AZP_URL})" `
    --auth PAT `
    --token "$(Get-Content ${Env:AZP_TOKEN_FILE})" `
    --pool "$(if (Test-Path Env:AZP_POOL) { ${Env:AZP_POOL} } else { 'Default' })" `
    --work "$(if (Test-Path Env:AZP_WORK) { ${Env:AZP_WORK} } else { '_work' })" `
    --replace

  Write-Host "4. Running Azure Pipelines agent..." -ForegroundColor Cyan

  .\run.cmd
}
finally
{
  Write-Host "Cleanup. Removing Azure Pipelines agent..." -ForegroundColor Cyan

  .\config.cmd remove --unattended `
    --auth PAT `
    --token "$(Get-Content ${Env:AZP_TOKEN_FILE})"
}
```

**UPDATE** 
I managed to get the answer i was looking for on the following
https://github.com/jakobehn/WindowsContainerBuildImage/blob/master/Dockerfile

Answer (score 0):

I was able to to get it working with the following **dockerfile**

```
# escape=`
FROM microsoft/dotnet-framework:4.7.2-sdk-windowsservercore-ltsc2016

ENV DOTNET_RUNNING_IN_CONTAINER=true `
    DOTNET_USE_POLLING_FILE_WATCHER=true `
    NUGET_XMLDOC_MODE=skip

SHELL ["powershell", "-Command", "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue';"]

# Install WebDeploy and NuGet with Chocolatey
RUN Install-PackageProvider -Name chocolatey -RequiredVersion 2.8.5.130 -Force; `
    Install-Package -Name nodejs.install -RequiredVersion 11.6.0 -Force; `
    Install-Package -Name webdeploy -RequiredVersion 3.6.0 -Force; `
    Install-Package nuget.commandline -RequiredVersion 4.9.2 -Force; 

# Install Node.js
RUN Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://nodejs.org/dist/v8.12.0/node-v8.12.0-win-x64.zip -OutFile node.zip; `
    Expand-Archive -Path ./node.zip -DestinationPath 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs'; `
    [System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('PATH', $Env:PATH + ';C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node-v8.12.0-win-x64', 'Machine'); `
    Remove-Item ./node.zip


# Install .NET Core SDK
ENV DOTNET_SDK_VERSION 2.2.100

RUN Invoke-WebRequest -OutFile dotnet.zip https://dotnetcli.blob.core.windows.net/dotnet/Sdk/$Env:DOTNET_SDK_VERSION/dotnet-sdk-$Env:DOTNET_SDK_VERSION-win-x64.zip; `
    $dotnet_sha512 = '87776c7124cd25b487b14b3d42c784ee31a424c7c8191ed55810294423f3e59ebf799660864862fc1dbd6e6c8d68bd529399426811846e408d8b2fee4ab04fe5'; `
    if ((Get-FileHash dotnet.zip -Algorithm sha512).Hash -ne $dotnet_sha512) { `
        Write-Host 'CHECKSUM VERIFICATION FAILED!'; `
        exit 1; `
    }; `
    `
    Expand-Archive dotnet.zip -force -DestinationPath $Env:ProgramFiles\dotnet; `
    Remove-Item -Force dotnet.zip

RUN setx /M PATH $($Env:PATH + ';' + $Env:ProgramFiles + '\dotnet')


#Download Azure DevOps agent
WORKDIR /azp

COPY start.ps1 .

CMD powershell .\start.ps1
```